# tab into a disabled field - set a delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am a new angularjs developer and have been stuck on this for a bit. I have an input that updates on blur like so:

```
<input ng-model="vin.value" ng-blur="onVinChange()"
                       maxlength="22">
```

another select (custom built directive) relies on the result from onVinChange to be enabled or not.

here is the other select:

```
<auto-complete disabled="customer.selected.id === null || entryAlreadyInSystem || customer.selected === ''"></auto-complete>
```

the problem is when the auto-complete directive is already disabled from a previous attempt, if I go back into the input, change the entry, and try to tab in to the autocomplete again, the onVinChange fires, but the autocomplete is still disabled so it scrolls me all the way to the bottom of the page and the cursor doesn't move in to the autocomplete. What is the most angularjs way to solve this problem? I would like it so when the user tabs they are either allowed in to the input if it's enabled, or there's no scrolling action, so perhaps allowed into the input, then disabled. is there anyway to solve this without setting a delay on the disabled attribute?

Comment: Does this happen with `ng-disabled` instead of `disabled`?

Comment: for some reason ng-disabled makes the disabled action stop working all together...i did not write the custom directive myself, I will have to look into that...

Comment: That makes me think there's something wrong with the logic then.  I'd look into that, if I was you.

Comment: so it turns out the djanky behavior was being caused by a race condition around the variable ```entryAlreadyInSystem```...I solved it with a simple $watch, un setting the variable when needed...

Comment: Excellent news!  Glad you figured it out!